# How to force Testcontainers to use specific docker image?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I usually run my `spring-boot-test` junit sql tests on a `Testcontainers` setup like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mariadb:10.5.8:///test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
```

Question: when I omit the docker image value, like `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mariadb:///test`, how can I force to always use a fixed docker image version?

My goal is to provide a `test-commons.jar` that every project should include. So projects should all use the same default mariadb image defined in the commons jar, and not set the image explicit themselves.

Is that possible?

Comment: I have only heard about testcontainers, but `spring.datasource.url` is just a spring property and there are many ways to configure that; but I might be missing something here

Comment: @Eugene that's Testcontainers [JDBC URL support](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/).

Answer (score 1):

You can copy [MariaDBContainerProvider](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/51ee33bad751debcaf88a0e8b7d72818db3f6df1/modules/mariadb/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/MariaDBContainerProvider.java#L9), use "mymariadb" or "custommariadb" as the database type and set the desired version in `newInstance()`.